# MySQL: adding conditions in SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, select, conditional-statements

I am having a huge SELECT where I need to make some conditions.

Eg:

```
SELECT `t`.`title`, `t`.`price_paid`, `t`.`date_creation`, `t`.`date_upload` 
  FROM `table_name` AS `t`
 WHERE `t`.`date_creation` >= "'.$year.'-'.$month.'-01" 
   AND `t`.`date_creation` < "'.$year.'-'.($month+1).'-01"
```

I declare in PHP the values of $year and $month and I want the rest to be made in MYSQL (I have strong reasons I can detail if needed)

What I need is to make the `date_upload` empty (null or 0) and `price` also empty if the date_upload is not from the same interval as `t`.`date_creation`

Comment: can you dynamically create the SQL statement in PHP and pass a variable in to your query object?

Comment: Let's use parameters for your query with "?" (it's SQL syntax, not PHP). PHP side just add precalculated parameters value with bindValue(). To make them empty you can't use a WHERE but a CASE statement (just THEN NULL if condition is not met)

Comment: Please use [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @Matt Busche Sure I can, any ideas? the result of this/of the actual query is an huge array that I use to build an CSV report. I am using some already made libraries for that where I insert the query and the structure

Comment: @tadman thanks for the tip still I'm pretty safe as everything is coming within a framework and is not that easy to inject stuff in our data as there are some layers for exactly this type of things :)

Comment: @Adriano we are getting close. Not sure about the bindValue() but I will take a look. the CASE statement sounds so right ...

Comment: @VictorSpinei there is also an IF() function that can be used for that. Usually I prefer CASE when there is more than one option (but if you have a huge query...I suggest you profile performance to see what's better).

Comment: Are you using PHP to process the data response and then parse into the CSV? If so, you can simply use a loop and condition to replace the fields you want to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions so far seems to be:

-> MySQL Nested "If" in Select Queries

> IF(condition, value if true, value if false)

Something like

> SELECT `t`.`title`, 
>   if (`t`.`date_creation` >= "'.$year.'-'.$month.'-01" AND `t`.`date_upload` < "'.$year.'-'.($month+1).'-01" ,`t`.`price_paid`, '0') as `price_paid`, 
>   `t`.`date_creation`, 
>   if (`t`.`date_creation` >= "'.$year.'-'.$month.'-01" AND `t`.`date_upload` < "'.$year.'-'.($month+1).'-01" ,`t`.`date_upload`, '') as `date_upload` 
>   FROM `table_name` AS `t`
>   WHERE `t`.`date_creation` >= "'.$year.'-'.$month.'-01" 
>   AND `t`.`date_creation` < "'.$year.'-'.($month+1).'-01"

and other solutions seems to be Control Flow Functions

> CASE value WHEN [compare_value] THEN result [WHEN [compare_value] THEN result ...] [ELSE result] END

Found on http://komlenic.com/254/mysql-nested-if-in-select-queries/
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Don't do date math like that. if you're december, you'll be asking for MySQL to look for `2013-13-01` on the high end. Use actual mysql date math:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE t_date_creation BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND (now() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

AS for your query, it'd be an UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET date_upload = NULL, price = NULL
WHERE date_restriction_logic_here.
```

Comment: good point with the date. I will use SQL there still I need to cover the full last month from 1 to the end of it.

Comment: The Update is not working in my case. I do the query and I print the result in a CSV report file so no saving in db so far. Other suggestion?

Comment: seems like IF(condition, value if true, value if false) is the closest to waht I need, i will add the solution bellow